# Missing something?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

```
product_color
===
color_id (primary)
color_initial
red
green
blue

school_art
===
id(primary)
art_loc
series_code

set_color
===
setcolors_id
school_art_id
color_id
```

What I would like to do is:

Get the red, green and blue from **product_color** table where the `product_color.color_id = set_color.color_id` AND  WHERE the `set_color.school_art_id = school_art.id`

This is what I have, but being that it is not working, clearly I am missing something. Any help would SOOO gratefully appreciated.

```
$colors =
"SELECT * FROM
    product_color
JOIN
    set_colors
ON
    product_color.color_id = set_colors.color_id
WHERE
    set_colors.school_art_id = '{$school_art_id}'";

$colorresult = mysql_query($colors) or die(mysql_error());
$returncolors = mysql_fetch_array($colorresult);
```

Comment: What isn't working? PHP or your sql query?  Are you connecting to your mysql server?  Please provide more information on what is not working.

Comment: Could you post example data and an example result (both what you get, and what you actually wanted)? That would really help see what needs to be changed.

Comment: I get nothing. I don't get an error. But I don't get any results either. I want to just echo out the "Red",Green" and "Blue" fields but nothing is coming back The {$school_art_id} should just output into the query the school art id. I can already echo the $school_art_id

Comment: Try `echo $colors` and check that the query is correct.

Comment: If you get nothing it would mean no result is being returned. What is the nature of the relation between these tables? set_color sounds like it's an intermediary table between product_color and school_art (N-to-N relation).

Comment: Btw, if this is in plain PHP shouldn't the end of the query be `WHERE
    set_colors.school_art_id = ' . $school_art_id . '"` ?

Comment: Your table apparently is called 'set_color' but you're using 'set_colors' in your query. I would highly reccomend running a query in PHPMyAdmin or at very least printing it out if it doesn't return the result that you expect. Also you don't need to use '{$school_art_id}', '$school_art_id' is more than enough since you're using double quotes outside.

Comment: @AR: What are the curly braces used for? `${var_name}` probably works but what about `{$var_name}`?

Comment: @James - they'll evaluate what inside them as php code. Which makes sense if you're using some php expression or a variable variable. In this case it's two extra characters that do nothing meaningful.

Comment: And if $school_art_id is an integral, than single quotes are not needed as well.

Comment: @AR: Interesting. Didn't know about this possibility and could come in useful :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that since you say `school_art.id` you also want to pull in the `school_art` table. For that, you have to `JOIN` all three tables:

```
SELECT * FROM product_color
         JOIN set_color ON(product_color.color_id = set_color.color_id)
         JOIN school_art ON(school_art.id = set_color.school_art_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM product_color, set_color, school_art
WHERE product_color.color_id = set_color.color_id 
AND school_art.id = set_color.school_art_id
AND set_colors.school_art_id = $school_art_id";
```

This should work for the query.

Also you might want to use mysql_fetch_array() in a loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($colorresult)) {
    allColors[] = $row;
}
```

Now each element of `allColors` array will contain one result row so you can do whatever you want with it.